# Weighted Average only when other range is not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently, I have the following data :

[image: data]

Basically what I want to do is to fill the `'YTD' for FOB Target` with the weighted average between FOB Target and Sales Volume Target but only to the month in which FOB Actual is available (in this case, April) i.e Weighted Average of FOB Target with Sales Volume Target from Jan-Apr'18.

I want it so that when I fill the May'18 FOB Actual, the formula will take it into consideration and then recalculate the Weighted Average to FOB Target with Sales Volume Target from Jan-May'18.

Comment: Use if() so if the range is blank no calc otherwise calc...

Comment: What formula have you tried? You omitted the row and column labels from your 'sample data' (that you expect everyone helping you to retype) so a 'turn-key' solution is impossible.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i have updated the image with row and column number. For summing the sales volume one, i use the following : =SUMIF(F4:Q4,"<>",F5:Q5). I cannot figure out how to do similar things for weighted average.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the question title. Instead mark the working answer as accepted by clicking **`✔`**, on the left side of the answer.